# How to have condition inside count SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

I already tried this code:

```
    SELECT Count(Gender) As MaleCount, Count(Gender) As FemaleCount
    FROM [Session4].[dbo].[Survey]
    Where Gender = 'M' or Gender = 'F'
```

I can't get the accurate data when counting with two different conditions in one query.

Pictures below:

This is the result.

[image]

This is the original data

```
SELECT  TOP (1000) [Departure]
    ,[Arrival]
    ,[Age]
    ,[Gender]
    ,[CabinType]
    ,[Q1]
    ,[Q2]
    ,[Q3]
    ,[Q4]
FROM [Session4].[DBO].[Survey]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

count explain :

- `COUNT(*)` counts all rows
- `COUNT(column)` counts non-null value
- `COUNT(distinct column)` counts distinct non-null value
- `COUNT(1)` is the same as COUNT(*)

Use case/when + sum :

```
SELECT
    sum(case when Gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end ) As MaleCount,
    sum(case when Gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end ) As FemaleCount
FROM [Session4].[dbo].[Survey]
```

will produce somethings like this :

```
MaleCount | FemaleCount
1000      | 1255
```

Another way is using simple goup by

```
SELECT
    Gender,
    Count(*)
FROM [Session4].[dbo].[Survey]
GROUP BY
    Gender
```

will produce :

```
Gender | Count
M      | 1000
F      | 1255
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this out:

```
   SELECT sum(case when Gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) As MaleCount, 
   sum(case when Gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) As FemaleCount
   FROM [Session4].[dbo].[Survey]
```

Let me know in case of any doubts.